# Bootstrap columns for extra small screen size devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to make a responsive columns using bootstrap. In desktop and large screen sizes it should have 4 columns. In Tab viewpots it should have 3 columns and in extra small viewports it should be 2 columns.

This is my Markup -

```html
<nav class="page-footer-nav row">
  <div class="footer-nav-section col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <a href="">Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-nav-section col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <a href="">Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-nav-section col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <a href="">Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-nav-section col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
    <a href="">Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
    <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

This markup working properly in small, desktop and large screen sizes. But it has a mess in extra small size. Check this [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/yixinejoka/1/edit?html,css,output) for better understanding.

This is a screen shot in xs device size-

[image]

Comment: it works properly even in xs device !! can you explain more the issue please ?

Comment: @ZeRubeus, check this http://jsbin.com/jowovowati/1/edit?html,output

Comment: in xs device columns are not displaying properly. 1st and 2nd columns are ok. but 3rd and 4th

Comment: @ZeRubeus, I updated my question with a screen shot image of xs device size. That is your fiddle result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Clear floats (with the .clearfix class) at specific breakpoints to
>   prevent strange wrapping with uneven content:

In the **[Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets)** for the grid system they advise you to add a new div in between the columns to help it understand where the columns should clear. The div should have a clearfix class so the columns clear to the left and one of the helper classes so you can target a specific viewport.

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5269/)**

and add this between the two parts :

- you need to add a clearfix `<div class="clearfix visible-xs "></div>` to avoid this issue in xs devises

Like so  :

```
<nav class="page-footer-nav row">
      <div class="footer-nav-section col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="">Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-nav-section col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
        <a href="">Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
      </div>

    <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div> // < --- add this to fix the issue

      <div class="footer-nav-section col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 ">
        <a href="">Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
      </div>
      <div class="footer-nav-section col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 ">
        <a href="">Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
        <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: May need to remove `col-sm-4` as well

Answer (score -2):

```js
$('.page-footer-nav').each(function() {
    $(this).children('.footer-nav-section').matchHeight();
  });
```

```css
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.matchHeight/0.5.2/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script>
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.matchHeight/0.5.2/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script>

<nav class="page-footer-nav row">
  <div class="footer-nav-section col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> <a href="">Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a> 
  </div>
  <div class="footer-nav-section col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> <a href="">Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a> 
  </div>
  <div class="footer-nav-section col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> <a href="">Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a> 
  </div>
  <div class="footer-nav-section col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3"> <a href="">Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a>  <a href="">Sub Menu Item</a> 
  </div>
</nav>
```

Your problem is a content inside the footer-nav-section. The problem is height of the div. You need to make all div's equal height.

Use [matchheight.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.matchHeight/0.5.2/jquery.matchHeight-min.js)

and the function is,

```
  $('.page-footer-nav').each(function() {
$(this).children('.footer-nav-section').matchHeight();
```

});